# Could someone please help me identify this font?

Tags: font-identification

[image]I’ve tried dafont, whatthefont and similar searches with no luck. This is for a decal across the front of a service truck for a local repair shop. I added a second image. I know it’s not the ideal images of the font, but it’s all I have to go on and I don’t have a lot of experience with locating fonts. I’m trying to help someone replace the decal because was damaged in a wreck.

[image]

Comment: I'm wondering why the hand drawn sketch exists. Could be because the font is a custom design? (And therefore a font file doesn't exist.)

Comment: I was trying to create a better image to search with so I traced it from my computer screen.

Comment: That doesn't look like a font. It's clearly hand drawn.